# jquery - onclick content slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

i've got a problem with my javascript (i'm in a real beginner state so sorry for that)

Ive got a menu like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>    
   <li class="shownav"><a href="#">Services</a></li>    
   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>    
</ul>
```

And my content is similar to this:

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
     <div id="content">
          <!--Content here-->
     </div>
</div>
```

what i want to achieve is that when you click li.shownav, #contentwrapper will slide 30 pixels down and reveals a 2nd navigation bar

is there any way to trigger a div to go down 30 pixels ?

Comment: have a look at this http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ . Might be what you're looking for

Comment: You can (and should) do this first with css :hover and then you would add javascript to do the slide down. Jquery allows easy animation of the div i.e. $('.shownav').slideDown();

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu li.shownav').click(function() {
        //will auto slide down content below it for it to fit
        $('#navigationBar').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: where `navigationBar` is simply the id of your second nav bar

Comment: ´slideToggle()´ permits to hide your second nav bar if you click again on your link

Answer (score 1):

You should:

First aim to make the menu work in CSS alone (otherwise non-js browsers will simply not be able to navigate)

Here is a simple css horizontal menu with one level of submenu dropdown

css using :hover

```
.menu>li{float:left;display:block;padding:10px;position:relative;}
.menu>li.nav>ul,.menu>li.shownav>ul{display:none;position:absolute;top:2em}
.menu>li.nav:hover>ul{display:block;}
```

Html (slightly modified from authors:

```
<ul class="menu">    
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>        
    <li class="nav"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>        
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>     
</ul>
```

[Non javascript reliant one level cssmenu](http://jsfiddle.net/axZDB/8/)

And then start adding js (jquery or whatever). Here is a simple version of the above including a slideToggle animation onclick

.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.nav').attr('class', 'shownav');//this removes the css class that is targetted by the rules so .js will now take over
    $('.menu li.shownav').click(function() {
        //will auto slide down content below it for it to fit
        $('ul', this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[Finished jquery+css fallback menu with click](http://jsfiddle.net/axZDB/24/)

Comment: :) Thanks @nbrooks - I know the user was after just .js but only experience makes us aware we need css fallback. Thanks for +1